# Analyze text (lemmatization, edit distance)

Tags: c#, nlp, similarity, lemmatization

I need to analyze the text to exist in it banned words. Suppose the black list is the word: "Forbid". The word has many forms. In the text the word can be, for example: "forbidding", "forbidden", "forbad". To bring the word to the initial form, I use a process lemmatization. Your suggestions?

**What about typos?**
For example: "F0rb1d".  I  think use damerau–Levenshtein or another. You suggestions?

**And what if the text is written as follows**:
"ForbiddenInformation.Privatecorrespondenceofthecompany."  OR
"F0rb1dden1nformation.Privatecorresp0ndenceofthec0mpany." (yes, without whitespace)

How to solve this problem?
Preferably fast algorithm, because text are processed in real time.
And maybe what some tips to improve performance (how to store, etc)?

Comment: Not exact duplicates, but similar [ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246961/algorithm-to-find-similar-text) [tions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067105/detect-duplicated-similar-text-among-large-datasets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're two possible solutions as far as I know algorithms.

You could try to use dynamic programming , **LCS** (longest common subsequence). It will search original text for the desired word as pattern, I believe it's O(mn):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html

Although the easier would be to use text search algorithm. The best I know is **KMP** and it's O(n). For character comparison you could group them into sets like {i I l(L) 1}, {o O 0} and so on. Yet you could modify this for not matching all letters (forbid -> forbad).

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

So now you could compare benefits of these two and yours suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use RegEx Matches to check for words.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx